# mysqli_select_db() returns true, but I get "No database selected"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

as you can see my code down below, the method I used to detect does `mysql_select_db()` return true or false. It does return true but I still ge the "No database selected" error.

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $sql_username = "root";
    $sql_password = "password";
    $sql_db = "tryckstore";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $sql_username, $sql_password) or die("Error");
    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, "tryckstore")) {
        die("Error selecting databse.");
    } else {
        echo "ok";
    }
```

It used to work actually, then I suddenly get this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not simply pass the database name as the 4th argument to the `mysqli` constructor / `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: None of those lines EVER produce the error "No database selected". - if MySQLi isn't working for you though, consider this http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @Phil I did, same problem.

Comment: @hanshenrik I know PDO, but I want solution for this problem.

Comment: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before `mysqli_connect()` to get better error reporting from MySQL

Comment: Also, `mysqli_connect` will **never** return a *falsy* value so your `or die("Error")` is completely unnecessary. With the above reporting mode, you won't need to check return values of `mysqli_*` functions as they will throw exceptions if errors occur.

Comment: @BillHicks here is a suggestion, show us the code that actually gives you the error, then we can stop downvoting your post? :p

Answer (score -1):

Use this one:

```
 $host = "localhost";
    $sql_username = "root";
    $sql_password = "password";
    $sql_db = "tryckstore";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $sql_username, $sql_password,$sql_db) or die("Error");
    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, "tryckstore")) {
        die("Error selecting databse.");
    } else {
        echo "ok";
    }
```

//pass the $sql_db as your 4th argument in the mysqli_connect also 
for simplier approach:

```
 $host = "localhost";
        $sql_username = "root";
        $sql_password = "password";
        $sql_db = "tryckstore";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $sql_username, $sql_password,$sql_db) or die("Error");
```

Comment: try to var_dump($con)